# Почему не работают спецсимволы у Icomoon?

Tags: css, css3, шрифты, иконки

**При создании иконочных шрифтов на сайте Icomoon заметил спецсимвол который не работает. В папки demo тоже не работают эти спецсимволы.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**У них есть документация, но я не особо понял как это работает. Вот сама документация [Ссылка на Icomoon документацию.](https://icomoon.io/#docs/make-font)**

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/icons/  вот это посмотрите ... проще работать чем icomoon.io

Comment: @МаксимЛенский если бы я хотел попросить совета, то по другому сформулировал вопрос. У меня в макете другие иконки, и моя задача из них сделать шрифт и их использоваться. p.s Мне нужен ответ на конкретный вопрос, а не совет какую библиотеку мне использовать и что - то в этом духе (Это предложение позиционируется для всех), но все равно спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в demo в ячейке, где приведет пример спецсимвола, не было прописано font-family иконочного шрифта, и по этому даже там они не отображались. По этой причине я даже не мог подумать что проблема именно в этом ибо примеры с ::befor корректно отображались. Прошу прощения за орфографию.